# `MouseEvent.movementX | Y` is incorrectly double twice as large

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I'm not sure what I'm misunderstanding, but MDN seems pretty clear:

> The movementX read-only property of the MouseEvent interface provides the difference in the X coordinate of the mouse pointer between the given event and the previous mousemove event. In other words, the value of the property is computed like this: currentEvent.movementX = currentEvent.screenX - previousEvent.screenX. ([src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/movementX))

Yet, `movementX` and `movementY` seem to be exactly double the expected value. This isn't just happening *sometimes*, it's on every mouse event. On small movements, due to rounding errors I assume, `movementX` & `movementY` may be 1px smaller or larger than double the change in `screenX` and `screenY`. But if you sum up all the numbers over multiple movements, they are exactly double.

I'm using windows 10, chrome stable 79.0.3945.117.

Minimal reproducible example:

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');
let lastPoint = [0, 0];


div.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  let point = [e.screenX, e.screenY];
  let delta = point.map((v, i) => v - lastPoint[i]);
  console.log(`delta (${delta[0]}, ${delta[1]}). movement (${e.movementX}, ${e.movementY})`)
  lastPoint = point;
});
```

```css
div {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it is related to my DPI or the setting titled "Scale & Layout, Change the size of texts, apps, and other items". Setting this setting to 100%, and coordinates are as expected. I have this set to 200% normally, and the twice-as-large-movementX/Y behavior is observed. [This](https://github.com/w3c/uievents/issues/40) issue on w3c's github seems related.